# c# Is it possible get a reference of an object, get the object itself and change it, instead of assinging to a new object?

Tags: c#, object, reference, assign

I'm just curious if something like that is possible in c#. I don't know why would anybody want to do it, but it's still interesting if that can be done.:

```
public class Test
{
    public string TestString { private set; get; }
    public Test(string val) { TestString = val; }
}

    public class IsItPossible
    {
        public void IsItPossible()
        {
            Test a = new Test("original");
            var b = a;
            //instead of assigning be to new object, I want to get where b is pointing and change the original object
            b = new Test("Changed"); // this will assign "b" to a new object", "a" will stay the same. We want to change "a" through "b"
            //now they will point to different things
            b.Equals(a); // will be false
            //what I'm curious about is getting where b is pointing and changing the object itself, not making just b to point to a new object
            //obviously, don't touch a, that's the whole point of this challenge

            b = a;
            //some magic function
            ReplaceOriginalObject(b, new Test("Changed"));
            if (a.TestString == "Changed" && a.Equals(b)) Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think so, though I don't think it matters either.  When you create the new object and point the variable to the new object (the new space on the heap), if nothing is referencing the old object (the old space on the heap) then the garbage collector will quickly get rid of it, leaving you in a state logically equal to what you want to achieve.

Comment: On line `b = new Test("Changed");` where you say "// this will assign "b" to a new object",  technically, you should say "// this will assign a new object to "b"
`

Comment: Is creating a new object one of the conditions? If not, b = a; followed by b.TestString = "Changed" will change the value of the object. Though you'll have only one.

Comment: @alvaro Yes. It wanted to replace the object itself, not just its parts.

Comment: @CoolCodeBro Then, it's not possible. C# doesn't let you alter this kind of pointer

Comment: This is exactly the low level type of manipulation that .Net **REFERENCES** seek to avoid.  If you need that kind of functionality then go to another language like C++ where you can manipulate actual **POINTERS**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean "can I change the value of `a` to refer to a different object, simply by changing the value of `b`?" then the answer is no.

It's important to understand that the value of a variable is never an object - always either a value type value or a reference. I like to think of variables like pieces of paper, and objects like houses.

A piece of paper can have a value type value written on it (e.g. a number) or the address of a house. When you write:

```
var b = a;
```

that's creating a new sheet of paper (`b`) and copying what's written on sheet `a` onto sheet `b`. There are two things you can do at that point:

- Change what's written on `b`. This doesn't affect what's written on `a` even tangentially
- Go to the address written on `b`, and modify the house (e.g. painting the front door). This doesn't change what's written on `a` either, but it *does* mean that when you visit the address written on `a` you'll see the changes (because you're going to the same house).

This is assuming "regular" variables, mind you - if you use `ref` parameters you're effectively making one variable an alias for another. So for example:

```
Test a = new Test("Original");
ChangeMe(ref a);
Conosole.WriteLine(a.TestString); // Changed

...

static void ChangeMe(ref Test b)
{
    b = new Test("Changed"); // This will change the value of a!
}
```

Here we effectively have one sheet of paper, with names `a` (in the calling code) *and* `b` (in the method).

Comment: Yes, a is a reference and b is a reference. I want to get where that reference is pointing and change it in c#

Comment: @CoolCodeBro: No, `a` is a variable and `b` is a variable. Their *values* are references.

Comment: Okay, A has an address of the house written on it. B copies what's written in a. B and A have the same address of the house. Knowing the address of the house, can't we go to the house itself and change it. a will have the same address written, but now the house will be different, because B told somebody the address and they replaced the house

Comment: @CoolCodeBro: You can change the contents - but you can't change it into a completely different house. (In your case, `Test` doesn't allow you to change the `TestString` property, for example - so that part of the "house" can't be changed.)

Comment: @Yeah that's what I was curious about. That's why I made it impossible to change the string. I didn't want to change the paint, or door size. I was interested in replacing the whole house.